# where to download the ClearCanvas Imageviewer StudyManagement dll file and how to import it

Tags: c#, image-processing, clearcanvas

everyone, I have a project in C# using ClearCanvas SDK library. The dll file, i'm interested in is the ClearCanvas Imageviewer StudyManagement file. It is missing from the ClearCanvas Imageviewer dll file. The error I have implememnting

using ClearCanvas.Imageviewer.StudyManagement  is

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'StudyManagement' does not exist in the namespace 'ClearCanvas.ImageViewer' (are you missing an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Don jar\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TRYDICOM\TRYDICOM\Form1.cs   14  31  TRYDICOM

can anyones direct me to a site where I can download thid dll file. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried downloading latest tarball and compiling it yourself? I see it in their git repository at least: https://github.com/ClearCanvas/ClearCanvas/tree/master/ImageViewer/StudyManagement

Comment: I'm confused about the format on that site, I copied some code, but errors are showing up in C# and the code needs other code on that site to run it. They don't have a dll package such as the other ClearCanvas  files. I dont undrestand when one copies and paste the file to C#, there are many errrors. Do you have any other ideas. I will be grateful. thanks